# add layout as a view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a pretty complex layout defined in `xml` file , now I want to add this layout as a view using `addView` or something else.

As layout is pretty much complex , its pretty cumbersome process to write the code for layout and then add it as a view. So is there anyway to load layout `resource` and add it as a view.

***I want to add the layout into WebView***

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View myView = factory.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_id, null);
```

then use `addView(myView)`

Answer (score 9):

You can also reduce this to one line of code;

```
  View view = View.inflate(getActivity, R.layout.my_layout,null);
```

then add to your view.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is a ViewGroup (layout) 
You can use `InflaterService.inflate(id, ViewGroup)` and set the ViewGroup, it will set the current child(s) with the content of your xml.

Comment: then it is a ViewGroup and it you should be able to use the inflate method