# How to load a layout and add it to another layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-search

I want to load a layout XML file and ad the layout to the current content view.

So, if I get this layout over here:

[image: Layout without search bar.]

and if I hit the hardware search button, then I want to display a search bar at the top of the screen, like this:

[image: Layout with search bar.]

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465258/add-layout-as-a-view-in-android#6465303), I tried something like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_bar, null);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    layout.addView(v);
}
```

The search bar is a layout file named **search_bar.xml**. `R.layout.activity_main` is the main activity. `R.id.layout_main` is the id of the `RelativeLayout` which is the container in **activity_main**.

But I got an *error inflating class*.

How can I load a layout and add it to the currently loaded layout?

Comment: What error? Could you provide us the LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an obvious problem with your code. As was mentioned in a comment, please post the log here.

May I suggest another approach? You could include the search bar (either in your main layout or using the [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag) and set it's visibility to [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) until you need to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and combined several hints to the solution.
First of all, I used `LayoutInflater.from(Context)` instead of the `Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE` (although that doesn't seem to be the problem). Second, I used the `onSearchRequest()` method.

This is the result:

```
/**
 * Whether the search bar is visible or not.
 */
private boolean searchState = false;

/**
 * The View loaded from the search_bar.xml layout.
 */
private View searchView;

/**
 * This method is overridden from the Activity class, enabling you to define events when the hardware search button is pressed.
 *
 * @return Returns true if search launched, and false if activity blocks it.
 */
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    // Toggle the search state.
    this.searchState = !this.searchState;
    // Find the main layout
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    // If the search button is pressed and the state has been toggled on:
    if (this.searchState) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);
        // Load the search_bar.xml layout file and save it to a class attribute for later use.
        this.searchView = factory.inflate(R.layout.search_bar, null);
        // Add the search_bar to the main layout (on position 0, so it will be at the top of the screen if the viewGroup is a vertically oriented LinearLayout).
        viewGroup.addView(this.searchView, 0);
    }
    // Else, if the search state is false, we assume that it was on and the search_bar was loaded. Now we remove the search_bar from the main view.
    else {
        viewGroup.removeView(this.searchView);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```